# I have a problem in AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a problem with some of my validation code. Here it is.

```
function isEmailValid(email) {
    if( email  == "") {
        document.getElementById("emailMsg").innerHTML="<font color=red>Email cannot be empty</font>";  
    }
    else { 
        var emailRegexStr = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/; 
        if (!emailRegexStr.test(email)) { 
            document.getElementById("emailMsg").innerHTML="<font color=red>Invalid email</font>";   
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = getHTTPObject();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
                    document.getElementById("emailMsg").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
                    if(xmlhttp.responseText == "<font color=green>Correct !</font>" ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }      
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/register_function.php?email="+email,true);   
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
}
```

The below part of above code is not working properly.

```
if (xmlhttp.responseText == "<font color=green>Correct !</font>") {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

May be a stupid mistake I am newbie in PHP + AJAX.

here is the related PHP code

```
if (isset($_GET['email'])) {    
    $email=$_GET['email'];   

    if (!isUserExistsByEmail($email)) {
        echo "<font color=green>Correct !</font>";  
    } else {
        echo "<font color=red>Email already exisits</font>";    
    }    
}
```

here is gethttpobject function

```
function getHTTPObject(){

if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();

else {

    alert("Browser does not support AJAX.");

return null;

}
```

}

i need to know how to change the getHTTPObject function for synchronous scenario .

Thanks.

Comment: That regular expression is going to say that a **lot** of perfectly valid email addresses are invalid.

Comment: I'd also say that the code you have is _very_ fragile - what happens if someone improves the server to return better formatted html? eg `<font color="green">Correct !</font>` or moves spacing around etc?

Comment: ajax part is check if the email already availble in database and echo the value so to complete the whole validation if (xmlhttp.responseText == "<font color=green>Correct !</font>") should be true otherwise it is already in the database. This is a validation part in a registration form.

Comment: `"<font color=green>Correct !</font>"` is code for "Address not in database"? Oh my.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not a valid check to do - it definitely is. I'm just saying that the way you're doing it is likely to cause you a lot of problems. Why try to _exactly_ match the response text when you could just check it contains the word `Correct`... That said, I think Asaph's answer is what you're after

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on string-matching an arbitrary string - This is often error prone. Most likely there' a trailing carriage return in the response

Try doing:

```
alert('[' + xmlhttp.responseText +']');
```

in place of your if statement.

If the alerted value is not **exactly**

```
[<font color=green>Correct !</font>]
```

then you've got a problem. I suspect you'll get:

```
[<font color=green>Correct !</font>
]
```

or similar - in which case you need to modify your if statement as appropriate.

A better and less fragile approach would be something like this:

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText.indexof("Correct")>=0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

or even better just do:

```
return (xmlhttp.responseText.indexof("Correct")>=0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting `isEmailValid()` to return `true` or `false`? Because the way it's written it will return nothing. The nested function defined *inside* `isValidEmail()` returns `true` or `false` but that will get called asynchronously some time after `isValidEmail()` has finished executing. And it won't be called by by your code. It gets called by the browser so you'll likely never have a chance to examine the return value to check if it's `true` or `false`.

One way to change your code to accomplish the goal of having `isValidEmail()` return `true` or `false` is to make the `XMLHttpRequest` call synchronous, rather than asynchronous (SJAX instead of AJAX). That way `isValidEmail()` will block until it receives a response back from the server (or times out). Of course your user will be unable to do anything on the page while they wait for their email address to be validated. This may or may not be acceptable.

Also, as others have pointed out, your regular expressions and string matching may need a little tweaking but judging by the question, that's not specifically what you're asking about.

Comment: Good catch - I didn't spot he was returning from an asynchronous function. I'll +1 when I get more votes :)

Comment: ya i understand your point.And any idea to handle this async situation

Comment: Make the call synchronous, not asynchronous. You'll have to change the XMLHttpObject code.

Comment: im new in this thing can you advise me to how to change the getHTTPObject() function. code has attached to the post ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a better stuffs in both PHP and javascript. Like, the PHP script could output the result in XML or JSON. And the Javascript, on the client side would parse the string according the format.

I suggest you have a look at the following links:
For JSON (I personally prefer JSON to XML, and some ways JSON is much better than XML)

- http://www.json.org/example.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

For XML, simply google, I am sure you will get many results.

Eg:
in PHP:

```
$obj['result'] = 1;
$obj['color'] = 'green';
echo json_encode($obj);
```

in Javascript:

```
try{
    var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
}catch(err){
    alert("...");
}
```